# Differential of boundary morphisms in the moduli space of pointed stable curves

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Recall that first order deformations of a smooth pointed curve $(C,p_1,\ldots,p_n)$ are parametrized by $H^1(C,{\cal{T}}_C(−p_1−\ldots−p_n))$ and in the stable case is $Ext^1(\Omega^1_C,\cal{O}_C(−p_1−\ldots−p_n))$. On the other hand there are two well known classes of boundary maps

$$η_i:{\cal{M}}_{i,k+1}\times{\cal{M}}_{g−i,n−k+1}\to\overline{\cal{M}}_{g,n}$$
and
$$η_0:{\cal{M}}_{g−1,n+2}\to\overline{\cal{M}}_{g,n}.$$
The first one identify the last marked point of a genus $g−i$ curve with the last one of a genus $i$ curve. This map dominates the boundary divisor $Δ_{i,k}\subset\overline{\cal{M}}_{g,n}$. The Second map identify the last two marked points of a genus $g−1$ curve and again it dominates $Δ_0$. Can anyone give me some information about the differential
$$dη_i:H^1(C_1,{\cal{T}}_{C_1}(−p_{i_1}−\ldots−p_{i_k}-q))\times H^1(C_2,{\cal{T}}_{C_2}(−p_{j_1}−\ldots−p_{j_{n−k}}−q′))\to Ext^1(\Omega^1_C,{\cal{O}}_{C}(−p_1−…−p_n)),$$
where $C=C_1\cup C_2\big/q\sim q′$. Same for $η_0$. Is something known about this map?